# A name for "arrow crossings" in a directed graph that exists in time

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I’m a music theorist with little training in math, so forgive me if this question has an obvious answer that my Wikipedia reading didn’t reveal.

[image: Link to image]

The image linked above is a rooted directed graph and the nodes a, b (the root), c, and d are successive in time. In blue, I’ve counted how many arrows are active after each node. Is there a term for this counting of arrow crossings?
(This is an abstraction; in the less abstract version, the nodes are words of a sentence, the root is the verb of the sentence, and the arrows are syntactic dependencies like “nominal subject” or “direct object.”)
Again, apologies if this is something someone familiar with the subject learns very early on.

Comment: It is strictly speaking the size of a cut https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory) (generated by partitioning the vertices into left and right). But personally I would think this is way too much abstraction for the simple concept you have.

Comment: I fully agree with Michal Adamaszek. The concept of "cut" can be seen as a conceptualisation of "boundary" ; its use is in general connected for "weighted graphs" to the Ford-Fulkerson theorem (max flow-min **cut**)

Comment: Thanks so much Michal and Jean, I think "cut" does the job!